# Why don't print() and input() work in visual-studio-code for python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just installed visual-studio-code for Python and can run scripts but not any that interact with the console. If I try to do a `print()` or `input()`, I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

my launch.json looks like this for the terminal:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

Just this causes the error:
print('Hello')

Comment: Can you paste your code on your question? That way will be easier for us to visualize the problem

Comment: Does `print 'hello'` work? Then you are in a Python 2.x environment.

Comment: What is your shell set to?

Comment: just this causes the problem: print('Hello'). Without the parentheses causes a missing parentheses error. I'm running in Windows 10,

Comment: Python3 requires a parenthesis for printing.

Comment: I am using print() with parentheses.

Comment: What is the name of the file you are using to test this? This kind of error usually means you named something after a module in Python's stdlib. Otherwise this works fine for me on Windows 10.

Comment: The name of the file is demonstrateError.py

and it just contains:

print('Hello')

Comment: I also installed Anaconda as I was using Jupyter notebooks for Udemy online class. I wonder if that is interfering with VS Code.

Comment: i have Anaconda on my machine and python runs fine.